# What is in included in import

Tags: python, import

I am new to python so please excuse me if I am asking something simple. I am experimenting with the import function. I would like to know if import a module,  can I make classes from that module. Here is my code for the module:

```
class Parent(object):

    def override(self):
        print("PARENT override")

    def implicit(self):
        print("PARENT implicit")

    def altered(self):
        print("PARENT altered")


class Child(Parent):
    def override(self):
        print("CHILD override")


    def altered(self):
        print("CHILD, BEFORE PARENT altered")
        super(Child, self).altered()
        print("CHILD, PARENT altered")
```

and here is my code for the script which I want to import my module:

```
import test

dad = Parent()
print(dad)
```

I keep getting: NameError: name 'Parent' is not defined

Again, excuse me if I am getting it all wrong but why cant I simply create a class from the module I just imported?

Comment: The [modules tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) has a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

With `import test`, only the name `test` is made available in your script, and you can refer to `Parent` as `test.Parent`.

If you want to refer to your class simply by its name `Parent`, you should use `from test import Parent`.

Comment: So I will only be able to use the independent functions in test?

Comment: @EliBaum: You can use everything, you just have to refer to it as, e.g., `test.Parent` instead of `Parent`, just like the answer already says.

Comment: @EliBaum I'm not sure what you mean by "independent functions".